# Image is successfully built, but not shown in "docker images" results

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am trying to build a new docker image.

```
docker build . -t tg
.....
.....
Removing intermediate container ba85d1deadeb
 ---> 353fcb84af6b
Successfully built 353fcb84af6b
Successfully tagged tg:latest
```

But for some reason, after it is successfully built I could neither run it nor find it.

```
docker images
<none>                               <none>              c18e928477c3        11 days ago         1.01GB
...... a long list of unrelated images that are intermediate steps of the built process .....
```

`docker image ls` , `docker images -a` aren't helping either.

```
sudo docker run -i -t 353fcb84af6b
Unable to find image '353fcb84af6b:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 353fcb84af6b, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

when running `docker run -i -t tg:latest` result is the same.

The issue seems to be **specific to THIS particular image**... Other successfully built images DO show up after running `docker images`.

[Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/Victornovikov/489f132278c997c7f3e4b0a79c2d6cbc)

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: have you try `sudo docker run -i -t tg:latest` ?

Comment: same -- `unable to find image 'tg:latest' locally`

Comment: Can you please provide Dokerfile or complete log? And have you tried by building once again after removing all intermediate images?

Comment: @RohitJindal the gist is here https://gist.github.com/Victornovikov/489f132278c997c7f3e4b0a79c2d6cbc
the final built step takes a while. I removed all cached files and waiting for docker file to finish building.

Comment: have you try this command `docker build -t tg .`

Comment: Are there some steps fail in the image creation time?

Comment: Can you post your build log? 
Did you try to tun docker on and off (restart the service)?

Comment: If you use minikube look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348036/docker-images-disappearing-over-time

Answer (score 1):

On linux
try:
`docker buildx build --progress=plain --load .`

Answer (score -3):

1- In order to run docker commands, use sudo user.

WHY -> The docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo.

Get your images build with **sudo docker build -t tag_name --no-cache .**
To see the images - **sudo docker images**

Also, you cannot use tag with image ID - **Unable to find image '353fcb84af6b:latest' locally**

In order to run your image, you can either use JUST image ID or image_name:tag.

Comment: 1. I went through the process of setting up docker so that I can run it without sudo. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

I am using it here "just in case". This error does not seem to be driven by lack of access rights...

2. no matter how I try run the image it makes no difference. moreover it is not even showing up in the list of images on my machine