# Docker images disappearing over time

Tags: docker, minikube

I loaded some docker images running

```
docker load --input <file>
```

I can then see these images when executing

```
docker image ls
```

After a while images start disappearing. Every few minutes there are less and less images listed. I did not run any of images yet. What could be the cause of this issue?

EDIT: This issue arises with docker inside minikube VM.

Comment: Do you have any crons calling `docker prune` or some `docker rm` commands? We do this on our company servers because Docker doesn't remove any images by default (not even unused ones). Without some cleanup routines, Docker would use a lot of space soon (especially on dev/test environments or larger Docker servers).

Comment: Actually this is my local dev environment that I have set up according to some online tutorials. So if there are no such jobs out-of-the-box, then no, I have not configured any such jobs. I was very surprised when seeing my images disappearing, it seems really weird to me. It is true however that images are pretty big, like approx. 2 GB.

Comment: You could try `docker image ls --all`. Per default, Docker only hides intermediate images. I haven't worked much with manually loading image files, but maybe they're also hidden when not using the `--all` switch.

Comment: According to the images: Yes, they _could_ be very big. But this heavily depends on multiple things like used software/dependencies, expecience of the author and so on. 2GB is relatively large for Docker. Most images are not larger than a few hundred MB. Some are much smaller. For example nginx on alpine (designed for small images) take less than 20MB. But there are also big ones with multiple GB. Especially build/dev images.

Comment: I edited initial post with information that this issue is present with docker inside minikube VM.

Comment: Unfortunately using ```docker image ls --all``` does not show missing images either. Any idea what to try to help me figure out what is happening with my images? Or how to deploy them again for them to stay permanent?

Comment: No, but I'd assume that it's related to Minikube since Docker itself doesn't delete images. Maybe Minikube have some cleanup logic for unused images. I haven't really used Minikube. Went with [rke](https://github.com/rancher/rke) because it's the same environment for dev/testing and prod. Normally, you don't directly load images to the nodes. Instead, there is some [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) for images on k8s so no need to keep them directly local. You could try this when you want to stay on Minikube.

Comment: Can you try with simply `docker images`

Also, can you do a simple restart? ```sudo systemctl daemon-reload &&
sudo systemctl restart docker```

Comment: Also to view all images you could try: ```docker images -a```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) daemon runs inside [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) VM, I assume that you might hit K8s [*Garbage collection*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/) mechanism, which keeps system utilization on appropriate level and reduce amount of unused containers(built from images) by adjusting the specific thresholds.

These eviction [*thresholds*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/) are fully managed by [*Kubelet*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) k8s node agent, cleaning uncertain images and containers according to the parameters(flags) propagated in `kubelet` [configuration file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/).

Therefore, I guess you can investigate K8s eviction behavior looking at the certain thresholds, adjusted in `kubelet` config file which is generated by `minikube` bootstrapper in the following path `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`.

Comment: That's it! I now made new minikube VM with bigger disk (overriding default value) and issue does not occur anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As mention in @mk_sta answer to fix issue you need:

Create or edit `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` with

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
evictionHard:
    imagefs.available: "5%"
```

Default value is 15%

```
minikube stop
minikube start --extra-config=kubelet.config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
```

Or free more space on docker partition.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#create-the-config-file

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#hard-eviction-thresholds